# Why does this way of calculating volume of sphere give result two times smaller than it should be? Integrals/onion method.

Tags: integration, volume

I'm high school student, and they never taught us how to use integrals, but I tried to learn it on my own. So I don't understand most of the wikipedia explanations. I'd be great if someone could give me an explanation that doesn't use high level maths, so I can understand it. There are tons of sources on the internet, but I don't understand most of them.

I started by trying to compute area of circle. I started with a one-fourth of a circle, and given the definition of radian, I came up with this:

[image: one fourth of a circle with dimensions of it's sides]

So for one-fourth of a circle of diameter $R$, it's arc is $\frac{\pi}{2}R$. My reasoning is, that we can get area of this one-fourth of a circle, if we sum it's arc $r$ times, or $\int_{0}^{r} \frac{\pi}{2}R dR$, which correctly evaluates to $\frac{\pi r^{2}}{4}$. Lowercase $r$ is diameter of the target circle that we want to find area of, and uppercase $R$ is generally diameter of the circle I'm measuring (in this case going from $0$ to $r$.)

Please let me know if this is correct or if this is just a coincidence, but it looks like this is a way how to compute it.

Then I tried to extend this method to a sphere, but it stopped working. If we imagine one-eighth of a sphere, one of it's sides is $\frac{\pi r^{2}}{4}$. If we extend the side and sum it $r$ times, we should get volume of one-eighth of a sphere.

[image: one eighth of a sphere]

$$\int_{0}^{r} R^{2} \frac{\pi}{4} dR = r^3 \frac{\pi}{4 \cdot 3}$$

If we multiply this by $8$, to get volume of whole sphere (as this is one eighth of a sphere), we get $r^{2}\frac{2\pi}{3}$, which is, according to online sources, only one half of a sphere, not a full sphere.

Where did I make a mistake? It should be multiplied by $2$, but why? Did I forget something or is this method just a crap that doesn't work and the area of circle was just a coincidence?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it's "crap".  The first thing to notice is that your variable of integration $r$ cannot also be a limit of the integral.  So you have $r$ doing two jobs.  Somehow $r$ has to vary from $0$ to $r$, but then it can't be $r$.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Out of curiosity, if I wrote the area of fourth-circle as $\int_{0}^{R} \frac{\pi}{2}r dr$, where $R$ is the diameter of the circle I'm measuring and $r$ is generally diameter of any circle I'm measuring (in this case circle of diameter going from 0->R), would the integral (not the idea itself) make sense?

Comment: And one more question, is this general idea, not necessarily the execution, correct, as is this the onion method that I heard about? That I take small slices of an object and sum them n-times?

Comment: I think you have the right notion.  With upper-case $R$ the integral makes sense.

Comment: @SoptikHa That is the entire idea of integration- take infinite small pieces and add them up until you get the desired quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of integration for the circle worked because the area of the quadrant is the sum of the areas of arcs. Now for a sphere, this does not work because the radius does not decrease the same way. What you have calculated is the one-fourth portion of a cone. The correct way to do this would be as follows-

Let the radius of the sphere be $R$. At a particular height $x$, let the radius be $r$. From Pythagoreas theorem, $r^2=R^2-x^2$

$$V={\int_0^R}{{\pi}\over 4}r^2\,dx$$
$$V={{\pi}\over 4}{\int_0^R}(R^2-x^2)\,dx$$
$$V={{\pi}\over 4}\Bigl[R^2x-{x^3\over 3}\Bigl]_0^R$$
$$V={{\pi}\over 4}\Bigl(R^3-{R^3\over 3}-0+0\Bigl)$$
$$V={{\pi}R^3\over 6}$$

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. I drawed it and it started making perfect sense. This was really great explanation.

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help :)